# Transform List of Strings to List of objects containing those strings as field

Tags: java, for-loop, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List` of `String`s and I am trying to transform it into a `List` of `Object`s that have a `String` field. I achieved it with the following method

```
private void revertAllTypesList(List<LenderAdditionalPartyTypeEntity> allTypes, List<String> cachedTypeNames) {
        allTypes.clear();
        for(String name : cachedTypeNames) {
            LenderAdditionalPartyTypeEntity entity = new LenderAdditionalPartyTypeEntity();
            entity.setPartyType(name);
            allTypes.add(entity);
        }
}
```

I am almost certain that I can improve this by using Java8 Streams since I am able to make the vice versa transformation. Should I use .flatMap instead of .map function or there is other approach?

Comment: Modifying the paramether and outputting results in the paramether is a bad design. Paramethers are input, returned value is output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
List<LenderAdditionalPartyTypeEntity> result = cachedTypeNames.stream()
  .map(name -> {
    LenderAdditionalPartyTypeEntity entity = new LenderAdditionalPartyTypeEntity();
    entity.setPartyType(name);
    return entity;
  }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you've had a parameterized constructor you could do it in a cleaner way, like this:

```
List<LenderAdditionalPartyTypeEntity> result = cachedTypeNames.stream()
  .map(LenderAdditionalPartyTypeEntity::new)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `new` keyword is missing when calling the constructor

Comment: @Andronicus It was missing indeed but I've made it even more compact anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as follows:

```
allTypes.addAll(cachedTypeNames.stream()
    .map(s -> {
            LenderAdditionalPartyTypeEntity entity = new LenderAdditionalPartyTypeEntity();
            entity.setPartyType(name);
            return entity;
        })
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```